# Implicit destructor execution in function calling

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor, temporary, object-lifetime

I'm wondering what the standard says about the following piece of code. Can `string` destructor of temporary object be executed before calling `printPointer`?

p.s. VS2010 compiler doesn't complain about this code and works correctly.

```
void printPointer(const string* pointer)
{
    cout << *pointer << endl;
}

const string* func(const string& s1)
{
    return &s1;
}

int main()
{
    printPointer(func("Hello, World!!!"));
}
```

Comment: The temporary string is only destructed at the end of the statement. Someone can probably dig up the reference (something with sequence points?) but you can see it yourself: http://ideone.com/N3Brll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can `string` destructor of temporary object be executed before calling `printPointer`?

No, because temporary objects will be destroyed as the last step in evaluating the **full-expression** which contains the point where they were created, which means it will persist until the invoking of `printPointer()` ends.

From the standard [#12.2/4 Temporary objects
[class.temporary]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4):

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

And [#12.2/6 Temporary objects
[class.temporary]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6):

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call ([expr.call]) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

**[explanatory demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/911deaaf35927e6d)**